# After migration of this old project I'm getting this error and I have tried a lot of ways

Tags: flutter

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
> Duplicate class com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DownloadNotificationHelper found in modules jetified-exoplayer-core-2.17.0-runtime (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.17.0) and jetified-exoplayer-ui-2.15.1-runtime (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.15.1)

```
 Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.
```

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 52s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

The old project after migration shows this.

Comment: You might be using 2 video player plugins. Share your pubspec.yaml

Comment: it is not in question form, it might ask a question